# Couldn't receive json value in asp.net core web api

Tags: postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new in asp.net core. I tried to send json using postman and catch the data into web api controller

In my Controller

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Student Save(Student s)
    {
        return _student.Save(s);
    }
}
```

Student.cs

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Cgpa { get; set; }
}
```

By using postman, First i am sending as form data and i could successfully save the data
[image: Success]

But when i tried to send using raw, then it did hit the action but i couldn't get the data

[image: Problem]

Here, i am sending name=test and cgpa=3 but in controller i haven't got the value instead got the default value for name and cgpa.

Note: ID field is auto increment.

Comment: Wow - That version of Postman is so old, i’d recommend updating it.